# Hibernate, Tomcat hangs after a while

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, c3p0, mysql-connector

Im running my tomcat on amazon vm, with amazon RDS, recently i noticed that if RDS has to restart then my webapp loses connection to it and no api requests would complete. That's when i discovered connection pool for hiberante c3p0.

My most recent issue is that after 6-12  hours of running tomcat would stop responding to the requests, then once i go to the tomcat server status i can see this on Threads

```
 Max threads: 200 Current thread count: 150 Current thread busy: 150..
```

Also with stock of api calls that is being holed with huge response time.
However on memory everything seems alright.
It almost feels like after some time hibernate starts to hang? although the number of connections on sql server is pretty low, less than 10.

I'm pretty sure i have something wrong in my hibernate config file, could please someone see if that see anything weird in there,

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://myapp.amazon.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
        <!--<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>-->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>


        <property name="hibernate.connection.username"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">default_schema</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>


        <!--Settings for c3p0 connection pool-->
        <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">60</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">30</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay">300</property>

        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.breakAfterAcquireFailure">false</property>-->


        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>

        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">select 1</property>-->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>-->
        <!--=======================-->


        <mapping resource="/mappings/...>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Best regards

Comment: Are you sure that you are closing connections in your application ?

Comment: i have try/catch blocks around those and am closing my connections in finally blocks. It is ok after restart for a while but then something just stops responding.

I mean that after restart i call the same apis and i can't see them start getting stuck. but after sometime it is stopping to respond and that pull of threads starts exceeding.

Comment: I suspet those connections are not getting closed.. I recomend you to use `jCOnsole` tool in JDK to know the opened connections in your JVM on your datasource https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html

Comment: if you are correct, wouldn then i be able to see that number of open connections on sql server?

Comment: yes you can see number of busy connections eventhough no hits to the DB from Application.